# Re-install problems

Tags: gnome, permissions, nautilus

I had to re-install Ubuntu, erasing all data, because my PC was overheating. (No problems with the fans, though.) After re-install, I have no permission to access a second HD. To fix that I tried nautilus, but received the following message:

```
root@hamilton-desktopN:/home/hamilton# nautilus

(nautilus:22731): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

** (nautilus:22731): CRITICAL **: Another desktop manager in use; desktop window won't be created
Nautilus-Share-Message: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: Falha ao executar processo filho "net" (Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado)
```

No other desktop manager was in use and Desktop window was created...

I am not sure what to do... Do I have installation issues?

Comment: Try using 'sudo nautilus'.

Comment: What's your question? Are you asking how to mount the drive or asking what those errors are? (They're normal, by the way.)

Comment: If the errors are normal, no problem then. (I was already a superuser when I called nautilus.) Now I can access my other HD.

Comment: @David - your friend, is not recomended to run graphical programms with sudo, instead, you can use ´gksudo´